# An exercise I made for myself on Uniform Continuity and couldn't solve

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to learn Uniform Continuity in Real Analysis, so I made myself some exercises to solve and improve on $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, but I couldn't solve one of the exercises:
"Prove that all functions of the form $f(x) = a\sqrt{x + b}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$". Here's what I tried: 
Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. For $\delta = ...$, we have that 
$|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon \iff$ 
$|a\sqrt{x + b} - a\sqrt{y + b}| < \epsilon \iff$ 
$|a(\sqrt{x + b} - \sqrt{y + b})| < \epsilon \iff$ 
$|a||\sqrt{x + b} - \sqrt{y + b}| < \epsilon \iff$ 
$|\sqrt{x + b} - \sqrt{y + b}| < \frac{\epsilon}{|a|} \iff$

But I don't understand how to continue from here. How should I continue this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the square root of negative numbers?

Comment: I meant uniform continuity on $[0, \infty)$. Sorry :)

Comment: Still a problem if $b < 0$.  Maybe you mean on $[-b,\infty)$.

Comment: Yeah (Extra characterssssss)

Comment: $|\sqrt{x+b}-\sqrt{y+b}|\leq \sqrt{|(x+b)-(y+b)|}$. For a slightly less mundane way to prove this, show that the composition of uniformly continuous maps is uniformly continuous, then show that the square root function is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, you want to find $\delta > 0$ so if $x,y \in [-b,\infty)$ and $|x-y| < \delta$, $|a\sqrt{b+x} - a \sqrt{b+y}| < \epsilon$.  Of course if $a = 0$, any $\delta$ will do, so let's suppose $a \ne 0$.  Now you want $|\sqrt{b+x} - \sqrt{b+y}| < \epsilon/|a|$, so it will be convenient to write $\epsilon/|a| = \nu$.  While we're at
it, we may as well get rid of that $b$, so let $s = b + x$ and $t = b + y$.  So now you want $\delta > 0$ so if $s, t \in [0,\infty)$ and $|s-t| < \delta$, $|\sqrt{s} - \sqrt{t}| < \nu$.

We break things up into two cases, one where $s$ is close to $0$ and one where it isn't.  Let's see: if $s \le \alpha$ and $|s-t| \le \alpha$, then $t \le 2 \alpha$, and $|\sqrt{s} - \sqrt{t}| \le \max(\sqrt{s}, \sqrt{t}) \le \sqrt{2\alpha}$.  So for this part, we want $\sqrt{2\alpha} < \nu$, and we can take $0 < \alpha < \nu^2/2$.
Thus if $s \in [0, \alpha]$ $t \in [0,\infty)$ and $|s-t| < \alpha$, $|\sqrt{s} - \sqrt{t}| < \nu$.

For the second case, where $s \ge \alpha$, we can use

$$ \left|\sqrt{s} - \sqrt{t}\right| = \frac{|s-t|}{\sqrt{s}+\sqrt{t}} \le \frac{|s-t|}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$$

This $< \nu$ if $|s-t| < \nu \sqrt{\alpha}$.

So we take $\delta < \min(\alpha, \nu \sqrt{\alpha})$, and we're done.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain this part? "So now you want δ>0 so if s,t∈[0,∞) and |s−t|<δ, |s√−t√|<ν."?

Comment: $|s - t| = |x-y|$ and $\sqrt{s} - \sqrt{t} = \sqrt{b+x} - \sqrt{b+y}$.

Comment: Okay thanks! (Extra charactersss)